# Problem with Excel macro when using Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

When I try to record a macro doing a Vlookup from another sheet, a 1004 error message appears and shows a problem with the first line of the code created.

The error is in the first line:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[Suppliers and their bank accounts.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0)"
```

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[Suppliers and their bank accounts.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0)"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$431").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$431").AutoFilter Field:=3
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the address of the `ActiveCell`?

Comment: the active cell: H2

Comment: Is the other workbook open?

Comment: yess, it's open

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the error is when there is no worksheet named Sheet1 in the workbook being referenced in the VLOOKUP.

Comment: it's called sheet 1 and it's open, I really don't know the excel can't read it

Comment: it is working fine on the sheet that I created the macro on but when trying other sheets with the same data, the error occurs

Comment: it's now working i tweaked in the range abit, thank you guys.